# Linker can't find static lib

Tags: c++, linker, mingw

I want to use OpenSSL in my project, but the building fails. The linker can't find the static libs (ssl and crypto).

I'm trying to build with 64-bit version of mingw.

I set the searching directories, and added the -lssl -lcrypto flags too. The path, and the names are correct, but I got the same error with the linker.

[Build log](http://pastebin.com/9K4yWAdx)

I'm confused. Can anybody help?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Can you show the actual command line being used? Perhaps a partial listing of the directories involved.  Also the `-Wl,--verbose` option might be helpful - that'll tell the linker to dump information about how it's searching for libraries.

Comment: I got this: [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9K4yWAdx)í

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the library is incompatible with the compiler? The message says:

```
skipping incompatible (library path)
```

This could possibly mean that the library archive is incompatible with the compiler or may be corrupted. I would recommend that you re-download the library/re-install it before taking other actions. Also check to see that the library directory is correct. In some cases, mingw-ld along with other linkers may sometimes fail if the order is incorrect (not alphabetically ordered).